# HTTP Error in Swift 2

Tags: swift, http, swift2

Whenever I try to load a url or gain the data from a specific URL that follows the http:// format. Xcode returns me with this error

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

How can I fix/work my way around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you have to update your `info.plist` file by adding this key:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

Or you can add it another way and it will look like:

[image]

Or you can add a specific domain like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) Post here for that.

Comment: Add to the property list of: localization native development? (In the picture above)

Comment: No add above property called `NSAppTransportSecurity`

Comment: It worked thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Comment: It's a bad idea to just turn off ATS. Much better to just turn off the particular requirements for the particular domains you use.